# Scrapy not running in Cron Job

Tags: cron, scrapy

I am trying to schedule a python script using cron tab which should run every day at 9 am on MacOS.

Following is the command I am using in crontab -

`0 9 * * * /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3 /Users/abhishekshukla/Desktop/python_scripts/tool/automation_test.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1`

I am using python package called - advertools which is based on scrapy.

But the cron job is not running and throwing error -

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scrapy'

Below is my python script -

```
import pandas as pd
import advertools as adv

df = pd.read_csv(r'~/Desktop/python_scripts/tool/test_urls.csv',encoding='utf-8')

url_list = df['url'].values.tolist()

print(url_list)

adv.crawl(url_list, 'cron_test_output.jl', follow_links=False)

crawl_df = pd.read_json('cron_test_output.jl')

print(crawl_df)

crawl_df.to_csv(r'~/Desktop/python_scripts/tool/cron_output.csv')
```

I tried changing the path of python and running the same command in virtual environment. But it was throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Four things -

1. Make sure that you are importing scrapy and CrawlerProcess
   so include the following lines -

import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

2. You have to mention the path of binary file in the crontab file. So mention the below line on the top -

PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin (Might be different for you)

3. Make sure to add the following code in your python script -

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
YOUR SCRAPING CODE

4. If you are using advertools, you don't have control on where it saves the output.jl file. So the location will be be default this - /Users/username/output.jl